# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form_Vehicle.Label_VehicleAnim_Info' SA-MP Offline Library

Tags: c#

hope you all doing great, so the problem occurs when I call a static method on a different form,
this is the method I'm calling

```
public static void UpdateUI(int _index)
        {
            PictureBox_VehiclePicture.Image = VehicleList[_index].Image;
            Label_VehicleName.Text = VehicleList[_index].Modelname;
            Label_VehicleID_Info.Text = VehicleList[_index].Modelid.ToString();
            Label_VehicleType_Info.Text = VehicleList[_index].Type;
            Label_VehicleClass_Info.Text = VehicleList[_index].Class;
            Label_VehicleAnim_Info.Text = VehicleList[_index].Anim;
            ListBox_VehicleList.SelectedIndex = _index;
        }
```

This is where I call it

```
 private void Button_VehicleID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            Form_Vehicle._index = int.Parse(NumericUpDown_VehicleID.Value.ToString());
            Form_Vehicle.UpdateUI(Form_Vehicle._index);
        }
```

These are the errors

> ```
> **PictureBox_VehiclePicture**.Image = VehicleList[_index].Image;
>                 **Label_VehicleName**.Text = VehicleList[_index].Modelname;
>                 **Label_VehicleID_Info**.Text = VehicleList[_index].Modelid.ToString();
>                 **Label_VehicleType_Info**.Text = VehicleList[_index].Type;
>                 **Label_VehicleClass_Info**.Text = VehicleList[_index].Class;
>                 **Label_VehicleAnim_Info**.Text = VehicleList[_index].Anim;
>                 **ListBox_VehicleList**.SelectedIndex = _index;
> ```

Comment: Why would a static method know about your instance variables?

Comment: There is the main form which contains vehicles information where a button called 'search' is located,
when the search button is pressed, an other form is opened which provides options for searching

Comment: You can't access no-static members from a static method.  Non-static members are *instance* members and require an instance in order to be used.

Comment: Read more on [static methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)